# How to stop Eclipse from opening referenced projects?

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I open a project in Eclipse, it auto opens all referenced projects.

I'd like to open only the main project, and manually open the referenced projects as needed.

Also I'd prefer a solution that can be configured for just my personal development environment, as I work with a large team.

I'm using Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0), and doing Java development. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do following:
 1. Open `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace`
 2. And select **Never** or **Prompt**

[image]